# Integrity Measurement Architecture on Android

Tags: android, mobile, architecture, measurement, integrity

I would like to learn more about the reasons why IMA (integrity measurement architecture )wasn't included with Android. Any papers or readings are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links to a few papers on the subject:

[Beyond Kernel-level Integrity Measurement: Enabling Remote Attestation for the Android
Platform](http://profsandhu.com/zhang/pub/trust10-android.pdf)

[TPM emulator, TrouSerS & IMA on Android](http://csrdu.org/blog/2011/05/25/tpm-emulator-trousers-ima-on-android/)

[Jean-Pierre Seifert - Efficient Integrity Measurement and Attestation for Mobile Platforms](http://mobisec.org/2009/docs/1%20-%20Jean-Pierre%20Seifert%20-%20Efficient%20Integrity%20Measurement%20and%20Attestation%20for%20Mobile%20Platforms.pdf)